# У Log4j можно ли изменить цвет текста в консоли?

Tags: java, log4j

Млжно ли у Log4j изменить цвет текста в консоли System.out для отдельных уровней?
Например по принципу LogCat (info = blue, warning = yellow, error = red)?

Comment: System.err - красненький =)

Comment: какую проблему пытаетесь решить?

Answer (score 2):

Есть 2 способа:

1. Если консоль является ANSI совместимым терминалом то, можно кодировать ESC последовательностями цвет сообщений - [например см. сюда](http://blog.uncommons.org/2006/04/09/colour-coded-console-logging-with-log4j/)
2. Если консоль не таковой (как под Windows) - то можно направить вывод на [ChainSaw](http://logging.apache.org/chainsaw/index.html) и там извратиться со цветами всяко-разно безобразно.

Answer (score -2):

```
...
System.out.println(colorText("Any text", "BLUE"));
...
private static String colorText(String text, String color) {
        int x = color.equals("RED") ? 31 :
                color.equals("GREEN") ? 32 :
                color.equals("YELLOW") ? 33 :
                color.equals("BLUE") ? 34 :
                color.equals("MAGENTA") ? 35 :
                color.equals("CYAN") ? 36 :
                color.equals("WHITE") ? 37 :
                color.equals("BLACK") ? 30 :
                color.equals("BRIGHT") ? 1 : 0;

        return (char) 27 + "[" + x + "m" + text + (char) 27 + "[0m";
}
```

Comment: Во-первых, вы забыли проверить переменную окружения TERM, перед тем как выводить ESC-последовательности. И вот к чему это привело: http://i.stack.imgur.com/d6qLh.png

Comment: Во-вторых, что-то я не вижу в вашем ответе упоминания `log4j`...

Comment: ответ взял отсюда https://toster.ru/q/22091

Comment: Это как-то оправдывает предоставление неверной информации?..

Comment: Пожалуйста, постарайтесь писать более развернутые ответы. Уверен, автор вопроса был бы благодарен за ваш экспертный комментарий к приведенному выше коду.